# Is filtering on a checkbox value of false more efficient than filtering on a null date value?

Tags: soql

I have a SOQL query that selects all Accounts where a custom date field is null. Since [querying for nulls can lead to full table scans](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html), would it be more efficient to use a checkbox field instead and check if it's false? So instead of this...

```
[SELECT ID
 FROM Account
 WHERE Date_of_Event__c = null];
```

I used this...

```
[SELECT Id
 FROM Account
 WHERE Event_Occurred__c = false];
```

...would that be better? Or would it not make a difference?

Comment: I have additional selective filters on this query, but I wasn't sure if this non-selective filter would affect the selectivity of the query as a whole. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103659/unsure-if-my-query-is-selective) answered that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't make a difference. Null values are never indexed, and checkboxes are never indexed. Both will have the same abysmal performance and may time out or hit non-selective query errors. You'll want to use additional criteria, if possible, use a LIMIT statement, or in some other way limit the number of rows that need to be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this is to ensure that `Date_of_Event__c` is Indexed, and replace all `NULL` Date values with a value of `01/01/1969` or some dummy value, that way the Indexed value lives in the Index Tree so you don't need to do a full table scan.